# ACL, Node, and User exists in DB, but still no access

Tags: users

Trying to write a custom module tying in ACL with commerce_license (to purchase access to content), but I'm not sure I'm implementing the ACL API correctly. Everything seams to be in the database, however. I'm probably missing a step, but I'm not sure what that is.

User is uid 3. Node I'm trying to access is node/23. ACL is 16.

ACL is listed in acl table. Node is listed in acl_node table, with grant view only. User is listed in acl_user table.

```
mysql> select * from acl WHERE acl_id = 16;
+--------+----------------------+-----------+--------+
| acl_id | module               | name      | number |
+--------+----------------------+-----------+--------+
|     16 | commerce_license_acl | ACL_4_23  |   NULL |
+--------+----------------------+-----------+--------+

mysql> select * from acl_node WHERE acl_id = 16;
+--------+-----+------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| acl_id | nid | grant_view | grant_update | grant_delete | priority |
+--------+-----+------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
|     16 |  23 |          1 |            0 |            0 |        0 |
+--------+-----+------------+--------------+--------------+----------+

mysql> select * from acl_user WHERE acl_id = 16;
+--------+-----+
| acl_id | uid |
+--------+-----+
|     16 |   3 |
+--------+-----+
```

I've noticed that in the modules that use ACL, there are calls to "node_access_acquire_grants($node)" after the calls to  acl_create_acl($module_name, $acl_name), acl_add_user($acl_id, $uid), and acl_node_add_acl($nid, $acl_id, $read, $update, $delete, $priority), so I've added that, too. However, I'm still missing something. The acl data seems to be being recorded, but the node access records are not. I'm using content_access (which also uses the acl module), but not getting the behavior I want.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I was having was that my module didn't correctly implement one of ACL's hooks, [module_name]_enabled().

Prior to returning the grants, acl_node_access_records() checks to see if the module is enabled by firing off that hook, and does nothing if it doesn't exist.